# getting 403 Forbidden when trying to add bulk devices on IBM IoT Platform

Tags: postman, iot, watson-iot

I'm getting "403 Forbidden" when trying to use Postman in order to add a POST  call so that I can add bulk devices to IBM Watson IoT Platform

Comment: Using Advanced Rest Client did the trick. I found out that the orgin header needs to be "orgid.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com"; and it seems that you cannot override it in POSTMAN - it prevents you from doing so. The watson platform CORS implementation allows only either no orgin or orgid.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bulk add  endpoint `/api/v0002/bulk/devices/add` works fine for me in the Postman native app.  I get the

> 201 Created

back and they are created.

You are sparse on details but I'd guess you are using the chrome addon.  [Go Native](http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/03/14/going-native/) for the best Postman experience.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Chrome add-on. Will try with the native one.